# Probability of two phone calls longer than 24.5min

Tags: probability, statistics

```
Time(to the nearest minute)  Number of Conversation 
5-9                          2                      
10-14                        9                      
15-19                        20                     
20-24                        13                     
25-29                        8                      
30-34                        3   

Two of the converstations were chosen at random. 
Find probability that both of phone calls were longer than 24.5min
```

What I did :

$$\dfrac 8 {55} \times \dfrac 8 {55} + 2 \times \dfrac 8 {55} \times \dfrac 3 {55} + \dfrac 3 {55} \times \dfrac 3 {55} = 0.04$$

But the answer says 0.0370. Why is it so?
The time is rounded to the nearest minute so interpolation is not necessary right?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "Time to the nearest minute" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting a phone call longer than 24.5 minutes is (8+3)/55. Once you get this phone call, you have 54 choices left, and only (8+3-1) are longer than 24.5 minutes. So the probability is $$\frac{11}{55}\times \frac{10}{54}=0.037$$